# Python requests not receiving response cookies

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I am sending a GET request to this [url](https://www.uniqlo.com/ca/auth/v1/login) (mobile user-agent needed). When sending this request on my phone or in postman, it returns a cookie called `oidc.sid` but when i do this in python requests, it does not return any cookies.

Here is my requests code:

`get_resp = requests.get("https://www.uniqlo.com/ca/auth/v1/login", headers=headers)`

```
headers = {
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/70.0.3538.75 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1",
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is easy understand why you saw this, because `get_resp` is the response(last response) after redirects. Website set cookie in first response so you could not get any cookies in `get_resp`. Only need to set `allow_redirects=False` your question will be solved

```
import requests

headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/70.0.3538.75 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1",
        }
get_resp = requests.get("https://www.uniqlo.com/ca/auth/v1/login", headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)

print(get_resp.cookies)
```